# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined when trying to navigate to another component after webapi response

Tags: angular, authentication, routes, google-signin

I am trying to use social login from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login) and implemented and its working fine

1. I'm trying to make users use of google login - Works fine
2. Trying to access details of login user and send it to web api - Works fine
3. returns result from web api - works fine
4. The problem comes here after successful registration the response I get is "Success"
   Based on the result I'm trying to navigate the user to dashboard from home component as shown below. Then I'm unable to navigate him and throwing me this error
   "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined"

This is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SocialAuthService, GoogleLoginProvider, SocialUser } from 'angularx-social-login';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  socialUser: SocialUser;
  isLoggedin: boolean;  
  constructor(private router: Router,private socialAuthService: SocialAuthService) {}
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
    this.socialUser = user;
    this.isLoggedin = (user != null);
  });
    
  }
  loginWithGoogle(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(user => {
      this.register(user);
   });    
  }

  logOut(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signOut().then(() => this.router.navigate(['home']));
  }

  refreshGoogleToken(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.refreshAuthToken(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }

  register(user:any){
    var email = user.email
    var name = user.name
    var imageurl = user.photoUrl
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://localhost:44394/api/User/RegisterUser",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        LoginType : "google", Email: email, Name: name, ImageURL : imageurl
      }),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg:any) {
        console.log(msg);
        if (msg === "True"){
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }else if(msg === "Email exists"){
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }else{
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        }
      },
      error: function (msg:any) {
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

This is myrouting module.ts

```
 import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
    
    { path :'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent,
      data: {
        title: "Dashboard Component",
        description: "",
        keywords: "",
        ogUrl: "https://example.net/dashboard"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, how about if you use `HttpClient` for sending request rather than using jQuery ajax?

Comment: @YongShun - No I have no idea how to implement as I'm new to angular

Comment: I think this [tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/21/angular-http-post-request-examples) is good for use. The reason that suggests using `HttpClient` is that the `this` keyword **maybe** different when you use jQuery ajax. You can try to add `console.log(this.router);` in success callback to see what is the value.

Comment: Did you check if the route you have given here is the same as the one given in routing module ?

Comment: @Nikhil- Yes..Added my app-routing.module.ts file..Please check

Comment: @YongShun - Ok thanks for the link..Will try and update

Comment: If the response is "Success", it would go to 'home' route. Did you check if that route is given properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are accessing `this.router` from within jQyery Ajax method. You will need to pass correct context to the callback methods (success, error etc). Unless you do that, `this` will not point to the component instance that we want here.

To have `this` as component, you will need to store the component this in a separate variable and than pass that variable to the `context` option provided by jQyery:

Change your register function to:

```
    register(user:any){
       var email = user.email;
       var name = user.name;
       var imageurl = user.photoUrl;
       var that = this; // Here we are storing component this to that

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "https://localhost:44394/api/User/RegisterUser",
         data: JSON.stringify({
        LoginType : "google", Email: email, Name: name, ImageURL : imageurl
      }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        context: that, // Here we are passing the component this
        success: function (msg:any) {
        console.log(msg);
        if (msg === "True") {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        } else if(msg === "Email exists"){
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        }
      },
      error: function (msg:any) {
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      }
    });
}
```

Recommendation: Avoid using jQuery Ajax in Angular application. Angular has an inbuilt module called HttpClient module that you can use for calling API(s). Check this: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @Ritesh- No its still the same getting same error

Comment: @coder add context:this, above success. Check updated answer.

Comment: Yes it worked now but after redirecting to dashboard again for a few seconds it retuned back to home component

Comment: @coder, this might be issue with your dashboard component. If your undefined issue is resolved, please accept/upvote the answer 